# I'm not able to generate header file

Tags: java, android-studio, android, opencv

So i'm trying to generate header files using 'javac' since 'javah' has been deprecated since java8.

```
javac "D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java"
 -h "D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV"
```

The above is the code I used, where first parameter is my source and second parameter is my destination where header file will be saved. But I'm getting errors. Mainly it doesn't recognize anything I have written in my mainactivity file.

```
D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:3: error: package androidx.appcompat.app does not exist
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
                             ^

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:5: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
                 ^

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:6: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
                   ^

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:7: error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
                         ^

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:8: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
                      ^

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class AppCompatActivity

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            ^

  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainActivity
D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    public static ArrayList<float[]> processMat(Mat mat, float threshold) {
                                                ^

  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class MainActivity
D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

    @Override
    ^
D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class MainActivity

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:16: error: package R does not exist
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        ^
D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
            if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
                 ^
  symbol:   variable OpenCVLoader
  location: class MainActivity

D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                Log.d("Error", "Unable to load OpenCV");
                ^
  symbol:   variable Log
  location: class MainActivity
13 errors
```

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html the command maybe should be `javac -h "D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV" "D:\Android Projects\NativeOpenCV\app\src\main\java\com\example\nativeopencv\MainActivity.java"`?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, but I'm getting the same error with that also

Comment: Why did you tag this question with C++?

Comment: What does the `javac` command produce without the `-h` option?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I was trying to generate a JNI C++ class with the javah command so that is why I added. i have taken it out now.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It gives me invalid flag error

Comment: But this question has absolutely nothing to do with C++